# Adding a UITextField to a UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview

Hey I've been looking for this problem and also found some topics to my question but I'm obviously not getting what I'm doing wrong, so here's my problem I have a UITableViewCell and want to add a UITextField to it. So I setup a textField and add it to the cell in the cellForRowAtIndexPathRow:, but when I select the row or to be precisely the textField no keyboard or shows up and I also can't see a placeholder.

Here's my code:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    UITextField *textField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];

    textField.delegate = self;
    textField.placeholder = NSLocalizedString(@"Description", nil);
    [cell addSubview:textField];

    return cell;
}

- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView shouldHighlightRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return nil;
}
```

I would appreciate your help ;)

Comment: use [cell.contentView addSubview:textField]; instead of [cell addSubview:textField]

Comment: You're setting your frame to `CGRectZero` so it will have a width, height, x position and y position of `0`. You need to create a valid frame with `CGRectMake(x, y, width, height)`

Answer (score 1):

Simple: Do not do it like this.

Instead - subclass UITableViewCell, let it have a xib-file and put your gui components there. Then register your xib with a reuse identifier and cast the dequeued cell to your type.

If you add subviews directly to cells, you will get recycle problems. (I.e multiple subviews stacked on eachother).

There's plenty of guides about tableviews and how to properly do it.

You can also use prototype cells from storyboard, which is super easy. Although this doesn't let you reuse the cells in multiple ViewControllers without duplicating the prototype cell in storyboard.

Also, initWithFrame is almost stoneage-stuff. You should use constraints if you don't want to get crazy when starting to work with other screen sizes. (I.e. iphone 6 and 6plus + ipad)

Answer (score 0):

Because you called initWithFrame:CGRectZero . CGRectZero means, origin.x=0.0 orgin.y=0.0, size.width=0.0 and size.height=0.0. Therefore invisible. you should call initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0,0.0.100.0.40.0).
 Much better method is to use xib for custom cell design.

Answer (score 0):

On this line `UITextField *textField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];` you are providing a `CGRectZero` value to your frame so this will set `width`, `height`, `x position` and `y position` to `0.0` essentially which means it will not appear. So what you need to do is create a valid frame using `CGRectMake(x, y, width height)` like `UITextField *textField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 10, 100, 20)];`. This should create a valid new instance of a `UITextField` that has the correct frame. It might also be worth having a read of the [documentation from `UIView`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIView/initWithFrame:) for a good understanding of how `initWithFrame:` works. I say `UIView` documentation becaue `UITextField` inherits this method from `UIView`.

Answer (score 0):

I see you initialized the textField with a zeroed frame (`CGRectZero`). Try passing an actual frame such as:

```
UITextField *textField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(15, 15, 75, 20)]; //x, y, width, height
```

Also, you should be adding the subview to the cell's contentView:

```
[cell.contentView addSubview:textField];
```